# StackOverflowError when saving Jenkins system configuration

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins 2.23.

I made a change to the Jenkins system configuration (changed Artifactory settings from login+password to using the Credentials plugin). On saving the changes, I get a StackOverflowError. The stack trace is too long to post on StackOverflow, so I put it on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/p6w411mn

Similar questions that Stack Overflow suggested did not answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: uninstall the Jenkins Trigger plugin and restart Jenkins.
After restarting, I was able to save the Jenkins system configuration.